# Given three lines, find triangle

Tags: geometry, vectors, analytic-geometry

Given the following:
$$L:x+y=1$$
$$M:3y=2x+6$$
$$N:2x+y=6$$
Find point $u,v,w\in\Bbb R^2$ such that in the triangle $[u,v,w]$, $L$ is the perpendicular bisector of $[u,v]$ (condition *), $M$ is the median from $u$ (condition $**$), and $N$ is the altitude from $v$ (condition ***).

Here's my approach:

$$L:x+y=1\implies y=1-x; \text{ so let } x=t, y=1-t$$
$$M:x=t, y=\frac{2t+6}{3}=\frac{2}{3}t+2$$
$$N:x=t, y=6-2t$$

In my understanding, I need to come up with six equations in order to find the coordinates $(u_1, u_2), (v_1, v_2), \text{ and } (w_1, w_2)$. I have come up with five equations:

$$\text{ 1. } (u-v)\cdot (t,1-t)=0 \text{ (condition *) }$$
$$\text{ 2. } \frac{1}{2}(u-v)= (t,1-t) \text{ (condition **) }$$
$$\text{ 3. } (w-u)\cdot (t, 6-2t)= 0 \text{ (condition ***) }$$
$$\text{ 4. } \|(w-u)\times (t, 6-2t)\|=\|(v-u)\times (t, \frac{2}{3}t+2)\| \text{ (median $M$ divides $[u,v,w]$ into two triangles with equal area) }$$
$$\text{ 5. } (t,6-2t)\cdot (u-w)=0$$

I would appreciate if someone could please give me the following insights:

- Is my approach correct?
- What should the 6th equation be?
- Is there a less tedious approach to finding these points?
- Another thing is that there should probably be more than six equations, since there are some variables like $s,t$, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is obviously wrong, since five equations do not determine six variables. Instead, note that

- $M$ is the median from $u$, so $u$ lies on $M$;
- $N$ is the altitude from $v$, so $v$ lies on $N$;
- $L$ is the perpendicular bisector of $uv$.

Therefore, let $v=(k,6-2k)$. Reflecting this in $L$ makes $u=(2k-5,1-k)$, but $u$ must lie on $M$ so
$$3(1-k)=2(2k-5)+6$$
$$3-3k=4k-10+6$$
$$7k=7\qquad k=1$$
So $u=(-3,0)$ and $v=(1,4)$. The perpendicular from $u$ to $N$ is $2y=x+3$; $w$ lies on this line, so let $w=(2q-3,q)$. The final constraint, that of $M$ being the median from $u$, is equivalent to the midpoint of $vw$ – $\left(q-1,\frac12q+2\right)$ – lying on $M$:
$$3\left(\frac12q+2\right)=2(q-1)+6$$
$$\frac32q+6=2q-2+6$$
$$3q+12=4q+8\qquad q=4$$
In summary, $u=(-3,0)$, $v=(1,4)$ and $w=(5,4)$.